# How to handle mouseenter and mouseleave events in touch screen (Windows 8.1 and Internet Explorer 10/11)

Tags: javascript, jquery

For dropdown menu I used mouseenter (show menu code) and mouseleave (hide menu code) events for mouse (not touch screen).

Now I want to use that mouseenter and mouseleave code on touch screen also but after tap out mouseleave code is executing.

Comment: Take a look to hammerJs

Answer (score 1):

`mouseenter` is not a valid event for touch screens, technically, you don't have a mouse.

on touch screens it's recommended to bind the dedicated events, such as `touchstart`, `touchend` and `touchmove`.

for example:

```
 document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
  alert(e.changedTouches[0].pageX) // alert pageX coordinate of touch point
 }, false)
```

see more info here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml

hope that helps.

Comment: I think this is a valid question but maybe it's not been asked quite right. I believe the OP is asking how to support mouse events on devices that are touch-enabled. There are many laptops out there with touch screens yet the user still has a mouse.

Comment: The `touchenter` and `touchleave` events aren't valid anymore.